# One material card, Multiple animations using react-addons-transition-group

Tags: reactjs

I have a `<Card>` component from material-ui. It has a CardHeader, CardText and other pieces that come together to make the whole card.

I am able to use `react-addons-transition-group` to animate this card as it enters the screen (componentWillEnter). This works great with:

```
export class MyCard extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
      }

  componentWillEnter (callback) {
    const el = findDOMNode(this);
    TweenMax.fromTo(el, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});
  }

render(){

    return <Card>
                 <h1> Blah Blah Title <h1>
                 <CardText> Blah Blah </CardText>
               </Card>
    }
}
```

Then the above gets rendered in another component like so:

```
<ReactTransitionGroup> <MyCard> </ReactTransitionGroup>
```

Wrapping it in `ReactTransitionGroup` makes sure it calls the `componentWillEnter` gets called, and the animation runs. This works as expected.

**What I would like to do is multiple animations.** So, the Card comes in from the left, the CardText comes in from the top, and the h1 comes in from the right-- or something to that affect.

Ideally, I would just do something like:

```
    componentWillEnter (callback) {
        const el = findDOMNode(Card);
        const el = findDOMNode(h1);
        const el = findDOMNode(CardText);

        TweenMax.fromTo(Card, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});

TweenMax.fromTo(h1, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});

TweenMax.fromTo(CardText, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});
      }
```

Of course, this doesn't work.

So my question is, how do I go about parsing the `this` instance of the component so I can animate each individual part?

I couldn't really find much on `findDOMNode`. It doesn't seem I can add id tags to the different parts and use those in `findDOMNode`. Or maybe I'm going about it all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Simply [use refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) and access them in the this object:

So:

```
render(){

    return <Card ref="card">
                 <h1 ref="title"> Blah Blah Title <h1>
                 <CardText ref="text"> Blah Blah </CardText>
               </Card>
    }
```

Then you reference them in the animation portion like:

```
    export class MyCard extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
            super(props);   
          }

      componentWillEnter (callback) {
        const card = findDOMNode(this);
        const title = findDOMNode(this.refs.title);
        const description = findDOMNode(this.refs.description);

        TweenMax.fromTo(card, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});
        TweenMax.fromTo(title, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});
        TweenMax.fromTo(description, 0.4, {y: 100, opacity: 0}, {y: 0, opacity: 1, onComplete: callback});
      }

    render(){

        return <Card>
                     <h1 ref="title"> Blah Blah Title <h1>
                     <CardText ref="text"> Blah Blah </CardText>
                   </Card
        }
    }
```

You'll of course want to differ the timing and animations in each `TweenMax.fromTo` call but that should do it!

I guess it is worth adding some further reading, as string refs may get deprecated? Hard to tell:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/24/streamlining-react-elements.html#pending-change-the-refs-semantics

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/664212109056729088